# State is not updating after updating the payload?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

After calling `.updateOne` from `EntityAdapter`, my state doesnt seem to be updated with the latest payload when I call `useAppSelector` to get the state. I'm always getting the old value.

Here are my codes:

```
export const privateNotesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "privateNotes",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        noteEdited(state, action: PayloadAction<{ id: EntityId, content: string }>) {
            privateNotesAdapter.setOne(state, action.payload)
        },
        noteDeleted(state, action: PayloadAction<EntityId>) {
            privateNotesAdapter.removeOne(state, action.payload)
        },

    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            ...
            .addCase(editNote.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                console.log(action.payload)   //this returns the new payload
                privateNotesAdapter.updateOne(state, action.payload) //doesnt seem to be updating
            })
    }
});

export const editNote = createAsyncThunk<
    Update<PrivateNote>,
    PrivateNote,
    {
        rejectValue: requestError
    }
>("privateNotes/editNote", async (existingNote: PrivateNote, thunkAPI: any) => {
    try {
        const state = store.getState()
        const { content, id } = existingNote;
        await serveraxios.post(
            `/note/${id}`,
            { content },
            {
                // withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${state.auth.auth.accessToken}`
                }
            }
        );
        const payload = { id, content }
        console.log(payload)
        return payload
    } catch (error: any) {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({
            status: error.response.data.status,
            message: error.response.data.message,
        });
    }
});
```

For example, when I call `dispatch(editNote(...))` in the parent component to update the state, the `action.payload` in the slice shows that its the new value. But when I try to get the same state in the child component, it doesnt return the updated value.

```
//parent component
const PrivateNoteList: React.FC = () => {
    const privateNoteIds = useAppSelector(selectPrivateNoteIds)
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

    ...
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
    const handleSaveNote = () => {
        if (editId !== null) {
            dispatch(editNote({ id: editId, content: noteInput }))
        } else {
            dispatch(addNote(noteInput))
        }
        setNoteInput('')
        setEditId(null)
        handleClose()
    }
...

//child component:
const PrivateNoteExcerpt: React.FC<PrivateNoteExcerptProps> = React.memo(({ privateNoteId, setEditId, setNoteInput, handleOpen, index }) => {
    const number = index + 1
    const privateNote = useAppSelector(state => selectPrivateNoteById(state, privateNoteId))
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    console.log(privateNote); //I dont get the updated value
...
```

I'm also not sure if this is due to my child component being wrapped in `React.memo` too. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

> Using memo will cause React to skip rendering a component if its props have not changed.

here I can see that after `dispatch(editNote(...))` you are updating `noteInput` and `editId` so it shouldn't be because of `React.memo`.
it seems that `editNote` is `async` and here you are dispatching the action before waiting for the incoming data so this should be the problem try it this way:

```js
const handleSaveNote = async () => {
 //...
 await dispatch(editNote({ id: editId, content: noteInput }));
}
```